# adding foreign key reference when adding entity to doctrine ArrayCollection

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am receiving the below error when adding an entity to an Doctrine ArrayCollection of an parent entity.

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'job_fk' cannot be null
```

Here's the parent entiry

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject;

class Job extends \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject
{

    /**
     * @var integer $pk
     * @ORM\Column(name="pk", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
     protected $pk;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ajfit\Entity\JobRequirement", mappedBy="jobFk", fetch="LAZY", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $requirements;

    public function __construct(){
         $this->requirements = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Here's the child entity

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject;

class JobRequirement extends \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject
{

    /**
     * @var integer $pk
     * @ORM\Column(name="pk", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
     protected $pk;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="job_fk", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ajfit\Entity\Job", inversedBy="requirements" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_fk", referencedColumnName="pk")
     */
     protected $jobFk;

}
```

Here's the calling code

```
$job = new Ajfit\Entity\Job();

foreach ($addedRequirements as $requirementText)
{
    $requirement = new \Ajfit\Entity\JobRequirement();
    $job->getRequirements()->add($requirement);
}
```

The child entity adds fine, but the jobFk is not setting at all. i have cascade={"persist"} on the join, and i persist all when i have added all the childs, my question is, do i need to persist the parent before i add the childs? or am i missing something?

Thank-you for your time.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the line @ORM\Column(name="job_fk", type="integer") in JobRequirement and check it out again. Let me know if it worked.